# More accurate Excel percentage formatting behavior

Tags: excel, formatting, percentage, vba

Why does the following code produce '100%' in my percentage-formatted `cells(1,1)`

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(1,1).value = .05
```

EDIT: I made my question much simpler as the comments cleared up some of the confusion.

EDIT: I realized later that I accidentally changed my cells() value again to 100%. Because it happened at a particular place in my code, I thought it was some sort of rounding issue. My problem should be solved now :).

Comment: .05 of 1 is 5 one hundredths, or 5% is it not?

Comment: The cell format will not affect the value you assign it programmatically. If your code assigns a value of 5 to a cell formatted as a percentage it will display 500%, not 5%.

Comment: Well, 'myPercent' var is already formatted as a percentage in my code. So myPercent = .05 , to me, means .05%. But I guess that's not how the computer processes it.

I can do myPercent/100 before I change my cell's value, but the final result seems to almost always be '100%' for some reason.

Comment: Thanks Rory and MatthewD, I edited my question now to be more specefic

Comment: In you comment to Trum's answer you say the correct answer is there then overwritten.  The problem is most likely somewhere else in your code.  could you post more of the code?  The answers that have been provided should work.

Comment: Well, I looked at my code and realized that somewhere down the line I changed that cells value again to 100%. I didn't catch it because it happened before I looped, and so I thought it was some weird rounding thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily by setting the percentage in the VBA - so:

if your variable 'mypercent' is 0.05.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(1,1).value = Format(myPercent, "0.00%")
```

Would display as 5.00% as expected.

I hope that helps

Comment: Ahh, but if 'myPercent' is .05, I want the value to display as .05%

Comment: You've got me a little confused. 0.05 in Excel would be expressed as 5% as Excel works on a percentage of 0-1. If you wanted 0.05 as a percentage - you would need your variable to be 0.0005 or do:

Format(myPercent / 100, "0.00%")

Is that what you were after?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I actually tried this and for some reason the final output is 100% in my cell. It shows as the correct value for a moment until I keep stepping through my code. (I edited my question to make my answer seem more simple now)

Comment: Ahh, I made a mistake and overwrote it to 100% somewhere else... Thanks

Comment: No problem, easily done. I'm glad that's sorted for you